# Change MFSide Menu Table height Issue

Tags: ios, iphone

I have used MFSide Menu in Objective C.But When the textView edit , the height of table in SideMenu is increased. I have not known what problems occur. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame manually in `MFSideMenuContainerViewController.m` class file.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Side Menu Positioning

- (void) setLeftSideMenuFrameToClosedPosition {

    if(!self.leftMenuViewController) return;

    CGRect leftFrame = [self.leftMenuViewController view].frame;

    //set the frame manually
    leftFrame.size.height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    leftFrame.size.width = self.leftMenuWidth;
    leftFrame.origin.x = (self.menuSlideAnimationEnabled) ? -1*leftFrame.size.width / self.menuSlideAnimationFactor : 0;
    leftFrame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.leftMenuViewController view].frame = leftFrame;
    [self.leftMenuViewController view].autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}
```